# Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii

I need to replace all non-ASCII (\x00-\x7F) characters with a space. I'm surprised that this is not dead-easy in Python, unless I'm missing something. The following function simply removes all non-ASCII characters:

```
def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i)<128)
```

And this one replaces non-ASCII characters with the amount of spaces as per the amount of bytes in the character code point (i.e. the `–` character is replaced with 3 spaces):

```
def remove_non_ascii_2(text):

    return re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]',' ', text)
```

**How can I replace all non-ASCII characters with a single space?**

[Of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-string) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii) [myriad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609895/efficiently-replace-bad-characters) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737048/handle-non-ascii-code-string-in-python) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/python-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921815/help-replacing-non-ascii-character-in-python), [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273575/python-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-a-list-of-strings) [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866261/detecting-non-ascii-characters-in-unicode-string) [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667875/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-any-given-stringtype-in-python) [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000968/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-unicode-characters-in-a-python-regex) [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string) [opposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586903/sqlite-remove-non-utf-8-characters) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7) [stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522127/removing-non-ascii-characters-in-a-csv-file), [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870084/how-to-decode-a-non-unicode-character-in-python)  additionally address all non-ascii characters not  a  specific  character.

Comment: wow, you really took good efforts to show so many links. +1 as soon as the day renews!

Comment: You seem to have missed this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-string

Comment: I'm interested in seeing an example input that has problems.

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks, but that is the very first one that I mention.

Comment: @dstromberg: I mention a problematic example character in the question: `–`. It's [this guy](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Comment: This helped me out a lot, I was having trouble while HTML parsing, but the characters that was causing a `UnicodeEncodeError` weren't needed, so your code just replaced with something more readable and feasible. Thanks

Comment: If you want various somewhat better representations of the string in question, see the answers at [Python - Unicode to ASCII conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527434/507544) which use various useful options and charsets with `string.encode()`.

Comment: ... Or, to get `?` instead of spaces, use something like `print s.encode('ascii', 'replace')` => `ABRA?O JOS?` for `ABRAÃO JOSÉ`

Comment: Does the answer have to be in Python? Will you accept pre-processing input in something like `sed`, `awk`, or `perl`?

Comment: @jubilatious1 At this stage of the question's life, perhaps `sed`, `awk`, and `perl` answers would be interesting even if they are OT. But I would recommend putting them all in a single "X/Y answer", not separate answers. Usually a `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` answer could replace a Python answer if the code is running from e.g. a bash CLI where all four are generally available, not where actual Python scripts are running.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Your `''.join()` expression is *filtering*, removing anything non-ASCII; you could use a conditional expression instead:

```
return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])
```

This handles characters one by one and would still use one space per character replaced.

Your regular expression should just replace *consecutive* non-ASCII characters with a space:

```
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', text)
```

Note the `+` there.

Comment: @dstromberg: slower; `str.join()` *needs* a list (it'll pass over the values twice), and a generator expression will first be converted to one. Giving it a list comprehension is simply faster. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024).

Comment: The first piece of code will insert multiple blanks per character if you feed it a UTF-8 byte string.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I was assuming this to be Python 3.

Comment: *"`–` character is replaced with 3 spaces"* in the question implies that the input is a bytestring (not Unicode) and therefore Python 2 is used (otherwise `''.join` would fail). If OP wants a single space per Unicode codepoint then the input should be decoded into Unicode first.

Answer (score 70):

For you the get the most alike representation of your original string I recommend [the unidecode module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

##### Python 2

```py
from unidecode import unidecode
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return unidecode(unicode(text, encoding = "utf-8"))
```

Then you can use it in a string:

```
remove_non_ascii("Ceñía")
Cenia
```

##### Python 3

```py
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode("Ceñía")
```

Comment: interesting suggestion, but it assumes the user wishes non ascii to become what the rules for unidecode are. This however poses a follow up question to the asker about why they insist on spaces, to perhaps replace with another character?

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer. It doesn't work for the purpose of _this question_ because most of the data that I'm dealing with does not have an ASCII-like representation. Such as `דותן`. However, in the general sense this is great, thank you!

Comment: Yes, I know this does not work for _this_ question, but I landed here trying to solve that problem, so I thought I’d just share my solution to my own problem, which I think is very common for people as @dotancohen who deal with non-ascii characters all the time.

Comment: There have been some security vulnerabilities with stuff like this in the past.  Just be careful how you implement this!

Comment: Does not seem to work with UTF-16 encoded text strings

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes, how to handle/rewrite your wonderful code for Python 3 since [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3)? Error: **NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined**

Comment: This works for Python3 - if you use `unidecode(text)`. I got some quotation marks from funny unicode characters during a crawl this way.

Answer (score 31):

For *character* processing, use Unicode strings:

```
PythonWin 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
>>> s='ABC马克def'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ',s)   # Each char is a Unicode codepoint.
'ABC  def'
>>> b = s.encode('utf8')
>>> re.sub(rb'[^\x00-\x7f]',rb' ',b) # Each char is a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
b'ABC      def'
```

But note you will still have a problem if your string contains decomposed Unicode characters (separate character and combining accent marks, for example):

```
>>> s = 'mañana'
>>> len(s)
6
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> n=ud.normalize('NFD',s)
>>> n
'mañana'
>>> len(n)
7
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ',s) # single codepoint
'ma ana'
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ',n) # only combining mark replaced
'man ana'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an important observation. If you do find a logical way to handle the case of combining-marks, I would happily add a bounty to the question. I suppose that simply removing the combining mark yet leaving the uncombined character alone would be best.

Comment: A partial solution is to use `ud.normalize('NFC',s)` to combine marks, but not all combining combinations are represented by single codepoints.  You'd need a smarter solution looking at the `ud.category()` of the character.

Comment: @dotancohen: there is a notion of "user-perceived character" in Unicode that may span several Unicode codepoints. `\X` (eXtended grapheme cluster) regex (supported by `regex` module) allows to iterate over such characters (note: [*"graphemes are not necessarily combining character sequences, and combining character sequences are not necessarily graphemes"*](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html)).

Answer (score 15):

If the replacement character can be '?' instead of a space, then I'd suggest `result = text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode()`:

```
"""Test the performance of different non-ASCII replacement methods."""


import re
from timeit import timeit


# 10_000 is typical in the project that I'm working on and most of the text
# is going to be non-ASCII.
text = 'Æ' * 10_000


print(timeit(
    """
result = ''.join([c if ord(c) < 128 else '?' for c in text])
    """,
    number=1000,
    globals=globals(),
))

print(timeit(
    """
result = text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode()
    """,
    number=1000,
    globals=globals(),
))
```

Results:

```
0.7208260721400134
0.009975979187503592
```

Comment: Replace the ? with a another character or space afterwards if needed, and you'd still be faster.

Answer (score 9):

What about this one?

```
def replace_trash(unicode_string):
     for i in range(0, len(unicode_string)):
         try:
             unicode_string[i].encode("ascii")
         except:
              #means it's non-ASCII
              unicode_string=unicode_string[i].replace(" ") #replacing it with a single space
     return unicode_string
```

Comment: Though this is rather inelegant, it is very readable. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for unicode handling... @dotancohen IMNSHO "readable" implies "practical" which adds to "elegant", so i'd say "a bit inelegant"

Comment: notional -1 for calling non-ascii characters "trash"

Comment: @axolotl I meant no offense. If I recall correctly when I was writing it I was indeed dealing with very weird characters that are not from any alphabet.

Comment: I know :) it's a light hearted comment

Answer (score 9):

As a native and efficient approach, you don't need to use `ord` or any loop over the characters. Just encode with `ascii` and ignore the errors.

The following will just remove the non-ascii characters:

```
new_string = old_string.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
```

Now if you want to replace the deleted characters just do the following:

```
final_string = new_string + b' ' * (len(old_string) - len(new_string))
```

Comment: In python3, this `encode` will return a bytestring, so keep that in mind. Also, this method won't strip out characters such as newline.

Comment: new_string = old_string.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode()

Answer (score 2):

When we use the `ascii()` it escapes the non-ascii characters and it doesn't change ascii characters correctly. So my main thought is, it doesn't change the ASCII characters, so I am iterating through the string and checking if the character is changed. If it changed then replacing it with the replacer, what you give.
For example: ' '(a single space) or '?' (with a question mark).

```
def remove(x, replacer):

     for i in x:
        if f"'{i}'" == ascii(i):
            pass
        else:
            x=x.replace(i,replacer)
     return x
remove('hái',' ')
```

Result: "h i" (with single space between).

Syntax :  `remove(str,non_ascii_replacer)`
str = Here you will give the string you want to work with.
non_ascii_replacer = Here you will give the replacer which you want to replace all the non ASCII characters with.

Comment: Nice edit, adding an explanation. :-) And now that I get the idea of your code I like the approach. (And as promised I did my best with formatting it for you; I hope you like it.)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processing using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ <:!ASCII>+ / /;' file
```

Sample Input:

```
Peace be upon you
السلام عليكم
שלום עליכם
Paz sobre vosotros
```

Sample Output:

```
Peace be upon you


Paz sobre vosotros
```

Note, you can get extensive information on the matches using the following code:

```
~$ raku -ne 'say s:g/ <:!ASCII>+ / /.raku;' file
$( )
$(Match.new(:orig("السلام عليكم"), :from(0), :pos(6)), Match.new(:orig("السلام عليكم"), :from(7), :pos(12)))
$(Match.new(:orig("שלום עליכם"), :from(0), :pos(4)), Match.new(:orig("שלום עליכם"), :from(5), :pos(10)))
$( )
$( )
```

Or more simply, you can just visualize the replacement blank spaces:

```
~$ raku -ne 'say S:g/ <:!ASCII>+ / /.raku;' file
"Peace be upon you"
"   "
"   "
"Paz sobre vosotros"
""
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties
https://www.codesections.com/blog/raku-unicode/
https://raku.org

Comment: **Thank you jubilatious.** I've upvoted because this is very useful knowledge for me in general, even though it is OT for this Python question. You've been very helpful with Raku / Perl questions and I appreciate that very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
def filterSpecialChars(strInput):
    result = []
    for character in strInput:
        ordVal = ord(character)
        if ordVal < 0 or ordVal > 127:
            result.append(' ')
        else:
            result.append(character)
    return ''.join(result)
```

And call it like this:

```
result = filterSpecialChars('Ceñía mañana')
print(result)
```

Comment: Why are you checking if `ord()` returns a negative number? Unicode code points are all non-negative integers, but I'll be happy to learn something new. I do agree that it is a good defensive measure, but before that I'd try to catch e.g. a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my string contained things like `BelgiÃ` for België and `&#x20AC` for the € sign. And I didn't want to replace them with spaces. But wth the right symbol itself.

my solution was  `string.encode('Latin1').decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score -1):

Potentially for a different question, but I'm providing my version of @Alvero's answer (using unidecode).  I want to do a "regular" strip on my strings, i.e. the beginning and end of my string for whitespace characters, and then replace only other whitespace characters with a "regular" space, i.e.

```
"Ceñíaㅤmañanaㅤㅤㅤㅤ"
```

to

```
"Ceñía mañana"
```

,

```
def safely_stripped(s: str):
    return ' '.join(
        stripped for stripped in
        (bit.strip() for bit in
         ''.join((c if unidecode(c) else ' ') for c in s).strip().split())
        if stripped)
```

We first replace all non-unicode spaces with a regular space (and join it back again),

```
''.join((c if unidecode(c) else ' ') for c in s)
```

And then we split that again, with python's normal split, and strip each "bit",

```
(bit.strip() for bit in s.split())
```

And lastly join those back again, but only if the string passes an `if` test,

```
' '.join(stripped for stripped in s if stripped)
```

And with that, `safely_stripped('ㅤㅤㅤㅤCeñíaㅤmañanaㅤㅤㅤㅤ')` correctly returns `'Ceñía mañana'`.

Answer (score -1):

To replace all non-ASCII (\x00-\x7F) characters with a space:

```
''.join(map(lambda x: x if ord(x) in range(0, 128) else ' ', text))
```

To replace all visible characters, try this:

```
import string

''.join(map(lambda x: x if x in string.printable and x not in string.whitespace else ' ', text))
```

This will give the same result:

```
''.join(map(lambda x: x if ord(x) in range(32, 128) else ' ', text))
```