# Windows Python: Changing encoding using the locale module

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, locale, setlocale

Using Python 2.7

I am writing an abstract web scraper and am having problems when displaying (printing) certain characters.

I get the trace-back error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2606' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)` from printing the string containing the character.

I used the locale module to find out my OS supported settings, although I'm not certain I should use locale for my problem, and noticed the default settings where `(en_US', 'cp1252')`. I am trying to change it to `('en_US', 'utf-8')` but sadly to no avail.

```
#code for default settings
print locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

This is the code I used to narrow down my locale setting options. ( No problems here, the code is just so anyone that wants to, can follow along )

```
import locale
all = locale.locale_alias().items()
utfs = [(k,v) for k,v in all if 'utf' in k.lower() or 'utf' in v.lower()]

# utf settings starting with en
en_utfs = [(k,v) for k,v in utfs if k.lower()[:2].lower() == 'en' or 
            v.lower()[:2] == 'en'

print en_utfs
```

This gives the output:

```
[('en_ie.utf8@euro', 'en_IE.UTF-8'), ('universal.utf8@ucs4', 'en_US.UTF-8')]
```

Here is where my problem lies; with trying to change the setting to `en_US.UTF-8`.

```
[IN]: locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )
[OUT]: Traceback code ...
[OUT]: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Sorry for all the code, for some reason I felt the excessive need to do so.

Comment: `locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )` works fine for me, but I'm on Mac.

Comment: I don't know anything about Mac's but it must be because it's on a UNIX based platform, not windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales

I think in windows you need to set 'localewin' value instead of the locale name. Setting `locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'English_United States.1252' )` worked for me in windows. I also tried setting different locales `Dutch_Netherlands.1252` and they worked. Though this might not solve your problem of UnicodeEncodeError, but I think this atleast explains why you are unable to set the locale.

Comment: Right you are, setting a 'localewin' value registered, but did not fix my problem.

Comment: Although my coding problem isn't solved by this my answer is. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix my problem, but I found a work around by remove all non-ASCII characters. See stack answer [replace non ascii-characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full name. So for example use:

```
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_CTYPE, 'Chinese (Simplified)_People\'s Republic of China' )
```

instead of

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'zh_CN.cpk936')
```

If this was successful you should expect this result:

```
print(locale.getlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE))    
("Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China", '936')
```