# Scrapy: use pipeline to replace unwanted non-ASCII code

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

From Scrapy results, one unwanted nonASCII code `\u2013` (aka `character(150)` or `en dash`) was in the title, such as `u'Director/Senior Director \u2013 Pathology'`. I am trying to use pipeline to remove `\u2013` with a regular `,`.  But the following code didn't work. No error message be reported neither.

```
from datetime import datetime
from hashlib import md5
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import re
import string

class ReplaceASC2InTitlePipeline(object):
"""replace unwanted ASCII characters in titles"""

ascii_to_filter = ["\u2013",]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    for word in self.ascii_to_filter:
        desc = item.get('title')

        if (desc) and word in desc:
            spider.log("\u2013 in '%s' was replace" % (item['title']) )

            item['title']=item['title'].replace("\u2013", ",")
            return item
    else:
        return item
```

Comment: I'm confused about the else part. If its a for...else clause, generally there will be a break in for block. or is it indented wrong?

Comment: The code is modified from some codes I found on Github which was used to discard unwanted items. But I don't have a lot of experience with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this stackoverflow post [Replace non-ASCII characters...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space?lq=1), I came up with this code, which will filter out all non-ASCII characters in the titles.  For my situation, the non-ASCII characters are not needed, so it works perfectly for me.

```
from datetime import datetime
from hashlib import md5
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import re
import string

class ReplaceASC2InTitlePipeline(object):
"""replace unwanted non-ASCII characters in titles"""

def process_item(self, item, spider):

    def remove_non_ascii(text):
        return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i)<128)

    orig_titl = item.get('title')
    item['title'] = remove_non_ascii(orig_titl) 

    if item['title'] != orig_titl:
        spider.log("Non-ASCII character(s) was removed in '%s'" % (item['title']) )

    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\u2013"` should be unicode, so just replace:

```
ascii_to_filter = ["\u2013",]
```

with:

```
ascii_to_filter = [u"\u2013",]
```