# How remove occurrences of \*** in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing through a pdf file that I converted its content to strings and there are many occurrences of \*** (* meaning any symbol)happening inside words. For example:

> transaction,  a  middle ground  has seemed  workable\xe2\x80\x94norms  explicitly  articulated, backed by sanctions of the relevant professional associations

Using `text.replace("\\***","")` obviously does not work and so I was looking into using `re.sub()`.

I'm having trouble with the syntax (reg expressions) to put into the arguements and was hoping for some help with it.

Comment: Is `*` literally an asterisk or just any symbol?

Comment: Have you tried `text.replace("\\***","")` ?

Comment: * meaning any symbol @DYZ

Comment: It's the very epitome of "I thought of using GREP and now I have *two* problems"!

Comment: You do not have `\***` in your string. `\\ ` is the escape character of `\xe2`. You have three consecutive non-ASCII characters. Perhaps that's what you need to remove.

Comment: You are solving the problem the wrong way around. Removing these characters would leave "workablenorms". However, correctly *decoding* them (it's a UTF8 sequence) would insert an [en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how bout `text.decode("utf8")` ... thats what i think you actually want to do

or you could strip them out with

```
text.decode("ascii","ignore")
```

(in python 3 you might need to use `codecs.decode(text,"ascii","ignore")` (not entirely sure off hand))

Comment: Ignoring them is a bad idea, because the words on the left and on the right get lumped together.

Comment: I certainly do not disagree ... i just figured ignore was more in line with the original question...

Comment: @AshleyNewman If you find the answer useful, you should consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `^` not to filter any none ascii/utf8 character

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', ' ', text)
```

result will be

```
'transaction, a middle ground has seemed workablenorms explicitly articulated, backed by sanctions of the relevant professional associations'
```