# Remove Unicode code (\uxxx) in string Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

I have some Unicode string in a document. All I want is to remove this Unicode code or replace it with some space (" "). Example =""

```
doc = "Hello my name is Ruth \u2026! I really like swimming and dancing \ud83c"
```

How do I convert it to the following?

```
doc = "Hello my name is Ruth! I really like swimming and dancing"
```

I already tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20078869/5505608, but nothing happens. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: If the answer you linked didn't work, there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: i already tried `re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', text)`. the code works, but nothing changed @MarkRansom

Comment: That's because strings don't update in-place, they're immutable. You need to take the return value of `re.sub` and assign it back to `text`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encode to ASCII and ignore errors (i.e. code points that cannot be converted to an ASCII character).

```
>>> doc = "Hello my name is Ruth \u2026! I really like swimming and dancing \ud83c"
>>> doc.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
b'Hello my name is Ruth ! I really like swimming and dancing '
```

If the trailing whitespace bothers you, `strip` it off. Depending on your use case, you can decode the result again with ASCII. Chaining everything would look like this:

```
>>> doc.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').strip().decode('ascii')
'Hello my name is Ruth ! I really like swimming and dancing'
```

Comment: i've already tried to encode, the code works but still nothing change. thanks for your reply.

Comment: my purpose is to clean unicode code from the tweet that i've streamed. I tried the code to my tweet.txt which is contain 10 tweets.

Comment: which one? @timgeb

Comment: the one in the answer.

Comment: the unicode code still appears after using `tweet.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`