# How to remove from Python Dictionary Non ASCII characters and replacing with spaces

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
a = {'age': '12\xa0', 'name': 'pks\xa0\xa0'}
```

I wanted to remove all Non ASCII characters and replace with spaces.

For Removing Non ASCII character in non-dict we are using

```
''.join([i if 32 < ord(i) < 126 else " " for i in a])
```

But how to use for dictionary.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apply your string solution to each item in the dictionary.

Comment: What's your python version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078816/4909087), you can use `re.sub`, removing non-ASCII characters and replacing them with a space.

```
>>> import re
>>> {k : re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]',' ', v) for k, v in a.items()}
{'age': '12 ', 'name': 'pks  '}
```

This should work on python-3.x (python) as well as python-2.x (pyth**off**).

Comment: in respect of keys if value is also a dictionary then how do it?

Comment: @Prashant `{k : {k2 : re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]',' ', v2) for k2, v2 in v.items()} for k, v in a.items()}`

Comment: @Prashant It works superbly for me, and that regex filters out anything that is not ASCII.

Comment: `a2 = {'a1':{'name':'pks/xa0/xa0', 'age':'12/xa0/xa0'},'a3':{'name':'kps/xa0/xa0', 'age':'23/xa0/xa0'}}` and i applied `ans ={k : {k2 : re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]',' ', v2) for k2, v2 in v.items()} for k, v in a2.items()}`

Comment: @Prashant Lol.. those are forward slashes, not backward-slash escape sequences... that IS ASCII, made of valid ascii characters. (See /xa0 vs \xa0)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a list comprehension and `ord` just encode to ascii and ignore the errors:

```
In [106]: {key:value.encode('ascii',errors='ignore') for key, value in a.items()}
Out[106]: {'age': b'12', 'name': b'pks'}
```

If you want to replace with space here is an efficient way:

```
In [117]: def replace_nonascii(mydict):
              for key, value in a.items():
                  new = value.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
                  yield key, new + b' ' * (len(value) - len(new))
   .....:         

In [118]: dict(replace_nonascii(a))
Out[118]: {'age': b'12 ', 'name': b'pks  '}
```

Comment: Sure but what about the space?

Comment: @AntonvBR The question's title says *Remove*. But if this is not exactly what OP is looking for he/she should let us know.

Comment: @AntonvBR I've tried addressing the spaces requirement in my answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yup, just fixed!

Comment: Thanks! A bit roundabout, you _have_ fixed it, so props for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the non printable ascii chars like this; it applies the line of code you provided to replace non printable ascii by a white space, to each value in the dictionary:

```
def remove_non_printable_ascii(s):
    return ''.join([c if 32 < ord(c) < 127 else " " for c in s])

a = {'age': '12\xa0', 'name': 'pks\xa0\xa0'}

for k in a:
    a[k] = remove_non_printable_ascii(a[k])

a
```

output:

```
{'age': '12 ', 'name': 'pks  '}
```

Comment: I like your answer (which is why I upvoted it). My initial answer did have the exact same thing but it was dv'd so I changed it a bit.. ha

Answer (score 0):

Iteration on dictionary with `map` can be used:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    a[k] = "".join(map(lambda c: c if 32<ord(c)<127 else " " , v))
```

`print(a)` give following output:

```
{'name': 'pks  ', 'age': '12 '}
```

Comment: That will need a separate question.