# Remove non-ASCII characters from string columns in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have panda dataframe with multiple columns which mixed with values and unwanted characters.

```
columnA        columnB    columnC        ColumnD
\x00A\X00B     NULL       \x00C\x00D        123
\x00E\X00F     NULL       NULL              456
```

what I'd like to do is to make this dataframe as below.

```
columnA  columnB  columnC   ColumnD
AB        NULL       CD        123
EF        NULL       NULL      456
```

With my codes below, I can remove '\x00' from columnA  but columnC is tricky as it is mixed with NULL in certain row.

```
col_names = cols_to_clean
fixer = dict.fromkeys([0x00], u'')
for i in col_names:
if df[i].isnull().any() == False:
    if df[i].dtype != np.int64:
            df[i] = df[i].map(lambda x: x.translate(fixer))
```

Is there any efficient way to remove unwanted characters from columnC?

Comment: What is a NULL? Is it a `None`? Or a `"NULL"`?

Comment: Does something like `.map(lambda x: x.translate(fixer) if x != "NULL" else x)`  can be of any help ?

Comment: Dyz,  I think NULL is equivalent to "None"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, to remove non-ascii characters, use `str.encode` with errors='ignore':

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

To perform this on multiple string columns, use

```
u = df.select_dtypes(object)
df[u.columns] = u.apply(
    lambda x: x.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii'))
```

Although that still won't handle the null characters in your columns. For that, you replace them using regex:

```
df2 = df.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks coldspeed, this is very simple and great solution. may I ask what the first line in the codes means?

Comment: @JoohunLee It is an efficient way of determining the column names of string columns.

Comment: thanks, btw, is there a way to delete unwanted character except for  certain special character? for example, if I have \x00A\x00-\x00B, applying your codes will return "AB" not "A-B".

Comment: @JoohunLee If you want to retain ASCII characters, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20078869/4909087 Otherwise, you can use: `x.str.replace('[^\w-]+', '')` add more characters as needed in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

What is the trick with `NULL`?
If you want to replace string `'NULL'` with real `NaN` use `replace`:

```
df.replace('NULL',np.NaN, inplace=True)
print(df.isnull())
```

Out:

```
   columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD
0    False     True    False    False
1    False     True     True    False
```

Or you need replace `'NULL'` with empty string, use RegEx in `str.replace`

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(
               r"[\x00|NULL]", "") if col.dtype == object else col)

print (df.isnull())
print (df.values)
```

Out:

```
   columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD
0    False    False    False    False
1    False    False    False    False

[['AB' '' 'CD' 123]
 ['EF' '' '' 456]]
```