# Cleaning Twitter Data in Excel

Tags: python, excel, twitter

I am working on a project for school, but now with online instruction it is much harder to get help. I have a dataset in excel and there are links and emojis that I need to remove.

This is what my data looks like now. I want to get rid of the https://t.co/....... link, the emojis and some of the weird characters.

[image: screenshot of twitter data]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this in excel? or maybe python?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [reference](https://pythonexamples.org/python-string-check-if-alphanumeric/), I believe you could do a function like this:

```py
def checkChars(inputString):
    outputString = ""
    allowedChars = [" ", "/", ":", ".", ",",";"] # The characters you want to include
    for l in inputString:
        if l.isalnum() or l in allowedChars: # This line will check if the character is alphanumeric or is in your allowed character list
            outputString += l
    return outputString
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in Excel, however, you can easily load the Excel file into 'pandas.dataFrame' and then use regex to ignore the non-ascii chars:

```
file_path = '/some/path/to/file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path , index_col=0) 
df = df.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)
```

Here you can find an extra explanation about [loading an Excel file into a dataframe](http://loading%20an%20Excel%20file%20into%20a%20dataframe)
Here you can read about [more ways to ignore non-ascii chars in `dataframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874708/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string-columns-in-pandas)