# python: replace non-"normal" characters in a string

Tags: python

While iterating through different strings I sometimes stumble upon characters that contain strings such as "ś" or even just a " ' " and I want to replace those every single character with a simple "_".

So the code I would want is one that meets the following requirements: if character is not a,b,c....Z or a number then character = "_".

I wonder what is the most elegant way to implement such a code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '_', s)
```

Comment: Surely, you meant `s = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '_', s)`? I've edited your answer.