# How to remove &shy; from string?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape. On a website they use `&shy;` in the title.

Original html element: `<h1 itemprop="name">Pen&shy;­ne met sa&shy;­la­&shy;­mi en broc&shy;­­co­&shy;­li</h1>`

When I scrape it, it returns this: "Pen�ne met sa�la�mi en broc�co�li"

Every � is an `&shy;` in the string

I've tried string.replace('\u00AD','') / string.replace('­­',' ') but it didn't work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

scrape_url = 'https://www.ah.nl/allerhande/recept/R-R377934/penne-met-salami-en-broccoli'
# get the data
data = requests.get(scrape_url)

#load the data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

titel = soup.find('h1').text
print(titel)
```

Comment: please show your scraper code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space

Comment: is your source file utf-8 encoded ? you can see that in notepad++

Comment: How about this. string.replace('&shy;­',' ')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3, I managed to fix it as follows:

```
s = '<h1 itemprop="name">Pen&shy;­ne met sa&shy;­la­&shy;­mi en broc&shy;­­co­&shy;­li</h1>'
s.replace("&shy", '').replace(";\xad","").replace("\xad","")
```

which gave me the following:

```
'<h1 itemprop="name">Penne met salami en broccoli</h1>'
```