# Get rid of &shy; in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to remove the `&shy;` part.
(&shy is a code point reserved in some coded character sets for the purpose of breaking words across lines by inserting visible hyphens. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen#:%7E:text=In%20computing%20and%20typesetting%2C%20a,lines%20by%20inserting%20visible%20hyphens.))
But to remove it neither my code editor and bs4 can identify it.
Example:
html example code code :

```
<span class="lemma__main">Mut&shy;­ter</span>
```

Python code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlexample, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', class_='lemma__main').text)
```

return:

```
Mut<0xad>ter
```

note:
<0xad> refers to a blank space in sublime text 3, but not exactly as when I try to replace blank spaces at my string,
it just doesnt identify as one.
As in the interpreter it is just a blank space

```
response.replace(' ', '')
```

also  it doesnt work if i try to replace &shy in it:

```
response.replace('&shy','')
```

both return:

```
Mut<0xad>ter
```

I have already looked up the solutions given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335386/how-to-remove-shy-from-string)

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: `print(soup.find('span', class_='lemma__main').text.replace('\xad', ''))` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="lemma__main">Mut&shy;­ter</span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').prettify(
    formatter=lambda x: x.replace(u'\xad', ''))
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <span class="lemma__main">
   Mutter
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```