# Python regex to replace non ASCII characters such as long dash ,  ,etc. with single hyphen from text file sample.txt

Tags: python, regex, fileinputstream

Python regex to replace non ASCII characters such as long dash ,  ,etc. with single hyphen from text file sample.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for any of your code, something like this would suffice:

```
forbidden_chars = 'abcd'
text = 'abcdefghijklmnop....'

for i in forbidden_chars:
    text = text.replace(i, '-')

print(text)
>>>-----efghijklmnop....
```

Comment: I want to replace non ascii chars from text file