# how to remove special characters in python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to remove special characters in python dictionary?

```
output = [{'title': 'title 1\u200c',
  'subject': 'subject1\u200c','a'},
{'title': 'title 1\u200c',
  'subject': ['subject1\u200c','a','b']}]
```

This is what I tried:

```
output['title'] = s.replace("\u200c", "") for s in output['title']
```

Comment: I changed your `output` dictionary based on what you have written in your code, because the dictionary as you had written it wasn't valid (`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-11: truncated \uXXXX escape`) Please check that it is correct

Comment: I get syntax error because of "for"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't only a special character, those are Unicode Characters. To remove Unicode characters we can use the `encode()` python method. The encode will return a bytes object, and you can transform in string by using the decode method.

```py
In [1]: title = "subject1\u200c"

In [2]: title.encode("ascii", "ignore")
Out[2]: b'subject1'

In [3]: title.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
Out[3]: 'subject1'
```

For your list of dicts, what you need is something like:

```py
In [15]: output = [{'title': 'title 1\u200c',
    ...:   'subject': 'subject1\u200c'}, {'title': 'title 1\u200c',
    ...:   'subject': 'subject1\u200c'}]

In [16]: decoded_output = [value["title"].encode("ascii", "ignore").decode() for val
    ...: ue in output]

In [17]: decoded_output
Out[17]: ['title 1', 'title 1']
```

EDIT:

```py
In [20]: for i in output:
    ...:     for key, value in i.items():
    ...:         value.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
    ...:         print(value)
    ...: 
title 1‌
subject1‌
title 1‌
subject1‌
```

As you have a list of dicts, you have to iterate in the list, and for each item of the list (that are dicts) you will iterate again using the `items()` dict method.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: Can you please guide me to the  how can I edit subject In addition title?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language and I didn't understand your question, can you write it in a different way for me?

Comment: In my question I have subject and title 
I learned how can I fix the title but what should I do for modify subject

Comment: Ahh okay, I'll edit the answer with the subject part

Comment: was the edit helpful?

Comment: you're welcome :D can you mark my answer as the right one if it was helpful for you? thank you

Comment: Yes, Of course :)

Answer (score 2):

What are you iterating for? You just need to replace the character from the string using `str.replace()`.

```
output['title'] = output['title'].replace("\u200c", "")
```

This only changes value of the `'title'` key of `output`

```
{'title': 'title 1', 'subject': 'subject1\u200c'}
```

If you want to remove the character from *all* items in `output`, you need a loop.:

```
for key, value in output.items():
    output[key] = value.replace("\u200c", "")
```

Or, as a dict comprehension:

```
output = {key: value.replace("\u200c", "") for key, value in output.items()}
```

```
 {'title': 'title 1', 'subject': 'subject1'}
```

---

Addressing your comments

> I got this error for part one list indices must be integers or slices, not str

> I got this error for second answer: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

> Its array of objects

Let's say `output` looks like this:

```
output = [{'title': 'title 1\u200c', 'subject': 'subject1\u200c'},
          {'title': 'title 2\u200c', 'subject': 'subject2\u200c'}]
```

You want to do what I showed above to *each dict* in `output`. Just replace `output` from before with `elem`

```
for elem in output:
    elem['title'] = elem['title'].replace("\u200c", "")
```

```
[{'title': 'title 1', 'subject': 'subject1\u200c'},
 {'title': 'title 2', 'subject': 'subject2\u200c'}]
```

Or, using a list and dict comprehension:

```
output = [
    {key: value.replace("\u200c", "") for key, value in elem.items()}
    for elem in output
    ]
```

```
[{'title': 'title 1', 'subject': 'subject1'},
 {'title': 'title 2', 'subject': 'subject2'}]
```

Comment: I got this error for part one list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I got this error for second answer: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @user12217822 Then `output` is a _list_, not a _dictionary_ contrary to what you have shown in your question

Comment: Its array of objects

Comment: @user12217822 In that case, please edit your question so that the details are correct. I will edit my answer to handle lists of dicts once you have done so

Comment: I fixed it @user12217822

Comment: @user12217822 See the edited answer

Comment: I got this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: On what line? What `list` object is it trying to run `replace()` on? @user12217822

Comment: In this line:
    elem['title'] = elem['title'].replace("\u200c", "")

Comment: @user12217822 then `elem['title']` is a _list_, not a _string_ as you have shown in your question. Please take the time to understand what your inputs look like, and include _all relevant information_ in your question.

Comment: now I didn't get error but it doesn't work