# BigQuery: Convert a text column to UTF-8

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to start a [Vertex AI AutoML Text Entity Extraction Batch Prediction Job](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/text-data/entity-extraction/get-predictions#get_batch_predictions), but in my own experience, texts (`"content"` field in the JSONL structure), must also accomplish the following two features:

- Every text's size in bytes, must be between 10 and 10000 bytes: DONE
- Every text encoding  must be UTF-8: **UNKNOWN**

My original data is stored in BigQuery, so I'll have to export it to Google Cloud Storage for later batch prediction. To take advantage of BigQuery optimization, I want to accomplish the 2 previous tasks in the BigQuery data source table itself. I have checked Google's official documentation, and the closest I have got to some related information, is [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions); however not accurate VS what I want. BTW, the query looks as follows:

```sql
WITH mydata AS (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN BYTE_LENGTH(posting)>10000 THEN LEFT(posting, 9950)
      WHEN BYTE_LENGTH(posting)<10 THEN CONCAT(posting, " is possibly an skill")
      ELSE posting
      END AS posting
  FROM `my-project.Machine_Learning_Datasets.sample-data-source`  -- Modified for data protection
)
SELECT
  posting as content,  -- Something needs to be done here
  "text" as mimeType
FROM mydata
```

And `my-project.Machine_Learning_Datasets.sample-data-source` schema looks as follows:

| Field name | Type | Mode | Records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| posting | STRING | NULLABLE | 100M |

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @David Espinosa, BigQuery supports UTF-8 encoding for both nested or repeated and flat data. For your requirement, you can use the encoding flag `--encoding=UTF-8 or -E=UTF-8` as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load
).There is also a string function `SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(value)` which can be used to convert bytes into string. It replaces any invalid UTF-8 characters with the Unicode replacement character, U+FFFD. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer did the job, FYI:

```sql
WITH
  mydata AS (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN BYTE_LENGTH(posting)>10000 THEN LEFT(posting, 9950)
      WHEN BYTE_LENGTH(posting)<10 THEN CONCAT(posting, " is possibly an skill")
    ELSE
    posting
  END
    AS posting
  FROM
    `my-project.Machine_Learning_Datasets.sample-data-source` )
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(posting, r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '') AS content,
  "text/plain" AS mimeType
FROM
  mydata
```

**UPDATE:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078816/16706763) case has been considered, for an improved workaround.

Thanks!